# What's the cause of the error with wget "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable"

Tags: http, ubuntu, wget, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to download zip 1.3Gb from an external site through the command:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://{address}
```

There are connect with site through 443 ports in start and response from site - 200 to HTTP request from wget.

When downloading proccess've been reached ~93% one falls with error: "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable"

I tried re-downloads file with key -c (continue), but it not works: wget writes that zip downloaded complitely (but it's wrong)

Help me, please!